# How to frame dynamic sql statements using Tree in C#?

Tags: c#, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a C# module which will dynamically frame sql statements,The strategy which im thinking involves the Tree Data Structure,The values should be stored in a tree like structure

[image]

I have designed class like below to implement the tree

```
class T
{
    string tableName="";
    C[] column{get;set}
}

class C
{
    string className="";
    V[] value{get;set;}
}

class V
{
    string fieldVal="";
}
```

I need to implement a method which will consume class T and generate the sql as below

```
insert into T1(C1,C2,C3) values(V1,V1,V1);
insert into T1(C1,C2,C3) values(V2,V1,V1);
insert into T1(C1,C2,C3) values(V3,V1,V1);
```

This seems to be simple but I'm struck while implementing the method, Since i have no experience with Trees. I guess i have to use a combination of BFS and DFS, but im not sure how to proceed.
Please let me know how to achieve this, a code sample would be Great!

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems you need to solve:

1. How to convert the tree structure into a collection of all possible value sets.
2. How to convert a value set into a sql expression.

The first problem might easiest be approached by recursively iterating the columns, and collecting sets of values together into lists:

```
// convert tree into collection of value sets
public IEnumerable<List<string>> ExplodeValueSets(T tree, int cIndex = 0) {
    // recursive portion as long as there are more columns to process
    if (cIndex < tree.column.Length) {
        // recursive generate list for rest of columns
        var subResult = ExplodeValueSets(tree, cIndex + 1);

        // combine values in this column with recursively-generated
        // sets from rest of columns to build up larger sets
        foreach (var result in subResult)
            foreach (var value in tree.column[cIndex].value)
                yield return new List<string> { value.fieldVal }.Concat(result).ToList();
    } else {
        // base condition - all columns are processed, so return empty list
        yield return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

This will convert the original tree structure in your picture into the collection of lists:

- V1, V1, V1
- V2, V1, V1

From here, it's a simple matter to convert these value sets into SQL statements:

```
public string GenerateSQL(T tree) {
    var valueSets = ExplodeValueSets(tree);
    var sql = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var set in valueSets)
        sql.AppendLine(GenerateSingleSQLInsert(tree, set));
    var finalSql = sql.ToString();
    return finalSql;
}

public string GenerateSingleSQLInsert(T tree, List<string> values) {
    var sqlFormat = "insert into [{0}]([{1}]) values('{2}');";
    var table = tree.tableName;
    var columnList = string.Join("],[", tree.column.Select (c => c.className).ToArray());
    var valueList = string.Join("','", values.ToArray());
    var sql = string.Format(sqlFormat, table, columnList, valueList);
    return sql;
}
```

To pull it all together using your sample tree (I made all the properties and classes public in order for this to work properly):

```
T tree = new T {
    tableName = "T1",
    column = new C[] {
        new C { className = "C1", value = new V[] { new V { fieldVal = "V1" }, new V { fieldVal = "V2" } } },
        new C { className = "C2", value = new V[] { new V { fieldVal = "V1" } } },
        new C { className = "C3", value = new V[] { new V { fieldVal = "V1" } } } 
    }
};

var sql = GenerateSQL(tree);
Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

Output:

```
insert into [T1]([C1],[C2],[C3]) values('V1','V1','V1');
insert into [T1]([C1],[C2],[C3]) values('V2','V1','V1');
```

Comment: Hi Mate, this is exactly what i needed, splitting the process in to two does made a huge difference. Let me try to integrate this logic in my application and update the Question :) Thanks for the help